# Use array as keys for nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested, nested-lists

I have a nested array like shown below.

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];
```

Is there a way to use another, un-nested array as the key(s) for `arr1`?

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];
var arr2 = [3, 0];
var arr3 = [4, 1];

console.log(arr1[arr2]); // should return 'c' like arr1[3][0]
console.log(arr1[arr3]); // instead of arr1[4][1]; should return 'f'
```

Is there a function that allows me to do this?

Comment: Look at the lodash `get` function, I think it might be close to what you're looking for. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Comment: nothing built in to do what you are after, you will need to code it.

Comment: `const c = arr2.reduce((acc, el) => acc[el], arr1);` -> returns "e" because index 3 has "e", "f"

Comment: I think `arr2` should be `[2, 0]` and `arr3` should be `[3,1]`. You can write a function to do that.

Comment: `[3, 0]` should return `e`, not `c`, and `[4, 1]` should return `undefined`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own function that implements this behavior like so:

```js
function nested_access(arr1, arr2) {
    let ret = arr1;
    arr2.forEach((index) => {
        ret = ret[index];
    });
    return ret;
}

const arr1 = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];
const arr2 = [2, 0];
const arr3 = [3, 1];

console.log(nested_access(arr1, arr2)); // should return 'c'
console.log(nested_access(arr1, arr3)); // should return 'f'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple method with reduce to walk the tree. (I changed your example indexes since they were off)

```js
const lookUp = (arr, indexes) =>
  indexes.reduce(
    (acc, index) => acc[index],
    arr);


var arr1 = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f']
];
var arr2 = [2, 0];
var arr3 = [3, 1];

console.log(lookUp(arr1, arr2));
console.log(lookUp(arr1, arr3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value by iteratively accessing properties using an array of [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```js
function findValue (obj, propertyAccessors) {
  try {
    let result = obj;
    for (const key of propertyAccessors) result = result[key];
    return result;
  }
  catch {
    return undefined;
  }
}

const arr1 = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];
const arr2 = [2, 0];
const arr3 = [3, 1];

console.log(findValue(arr1, arr2)); // "c"
console.log(findValue(arr1, arr3)); // "f"
console.log(findValue(arr1, [2, 2, 3])); // undefined
```

If you attempt to access a property which doesn't exist, the result will be `undefined`. If you continue to attempt to access another property on `undefined`, an exception will be thrown. By using [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), you can catch such an error and return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getValue(arr, arrKeys)
{
  return arrKeys.reduce(
    (acum, current) =>  acum?.[current]
    , arr
  )
}

var arr1 = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];
var arr2 = [2, 0];
var arr3 = [3, 1];

console.log(getValue(arr1, arr2))
console.log(getValue(arr1, arr3))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an array method `Array#getNested` as follows:

```js
Array.prototype.getNested = function(index) { 
    let out = this; 
    index.forEach(i => out = out[i]); 
    return out; 
}

const arr1 = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g',['h',['i', 'j']]]];
const arr2 = [2, 0];
const arr3 = [3, 1];
const arr4 = [4, 1, 1, 0];

console.log( arr1.getNested(arr2) );
console.log( arr1.getNested(arr3) );
console.log( arr1.getNested(arr4) );
```